# Former question not in my question list

Tags: support

I can't find a question that I posed some weeks ago in my user accounts questions list. The question was on hold being to broad or not appropriate. Nevertheless some pittyful user brought in some helpful comments - that I would like to find again.

Where can I find this question? And if the question was deleted - how can I get information about this in the future?

Answer (score 3):

The question was automatically deleted by the system 10 days after being closed.

However, it surprises me that you can't see it — this may be a bug in SE.

Anyway, the recommendation made in the comments was:

> Take a look at the Microchip ENC28J60. It's a Ethernet MAC/PHY with SPI interface. – Olin Lathrop

Comment: Many thanks for digging this out.